# How can i make 2 Apsalar segments that do not overlap?

Tags: analytics

So I am running into an issue with where i need to divide my users into segments in Apsalar but it's based off of one event

The event only happens when running in debug (so testers), and while i can still make a segment for them in Apsalar i will run into the issue where testers have their events mixed in with players

The end result of this is that tester data and player data are separate and I keep track of both.

I can do this with Flurry because they allow me to segment based on NOT having an event, but I was wondering if there was a way to do something similiar with Apsalar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish your goal - separating tester data from player data - I recommend creating a unique application from within the Apsalar dashboard.

Doing so will allow you to divide your events, segments, cohorts, and other application data  into two clear buckets on Apsalar's platform. I believe it is better to ensure you are not duplicating the data you are reporting and analyzing in Apsalar than to create an event based on the absence of an event. If you create multiple segments based on NOT having an event, I guarantee it will be difficult to parse which segments belong to your testing and production purposes.

Let me know if this helps.

Image URL:
http://ge.tt/4tJJSJR/v/0